# NIFI attributes of flow file added in onTrigger() not showing

Tags: apache-nifi

Environment:

- NIFI version: 1.23.2
- JDK: OpenJDK 11.0.12
- OS: either in Ubuntu 20.04 64bit LTS or Windows 11 Pro

My processor and test are as below.

As you can see, I add new attributes in two places. One is in `TestSampleProcessor.java` for simulating that there are some existed attributes in the flow file. And the other place is in `onTrigger(...)` in `SampleProcessor.java`.

From the output log, you can see that the log in `onTrigger(...)` just could not find the attributes added in `onTrigger(...)` which are `IN_SIDE_ATTR_1` and `IN_SIDE_ATTR_2`.

But in the log in `TestSampleProcessor.java`, the attributes `IN_SIDE_ATTR_1` and `IN_SIDE_ATTR_2`, appear. Why ?

If I want the attributes `IN_SIDE_ATTR_1` and `IN_SIDE_ATTR_2` can be seen in `onTrigger(...)`, how should I do ?

### SampleProcessor.java

```
import org.apache.nifi.annotation.documentation.CapabilityDescription;
import org.apache.nifi.components.PropertyDescriptor;
import org.apache.nifi.flowfile.FlowFile;
import org.apache.nifi.logging.ComponentLog;
import org.apache.nifi.processor.*;

@CapabilityDescription("Sample processor for testing log message")
class SampleProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
    public static final Relationship REL_SUCCESS = new Relationship.Builder()
            .name("success")
            .description("Test")
            .build();
    private List<PropertyDescriptor> descriptors = new ArrayList<>();

    private Set<Relationship> relationships = new HashSet<>();
    private ComponentLog log;

    @Override
    protected void init(final ProcessorInitializationContext context) {

        log = getLogger();
        //  relationships =
        relationships.add(REL_SUCCESS);
        relationships = Collections.unmodifiableSet(relationships);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Relationship> getRelationships() {
        return this.relationships;
    }


    @Override
    public void onTrigger(final ProcessContext context, final ProcessSession session) {
        FlowFile flowFile = session.get();
        if (flowFile == null) return;
        InputStream inputStream = session.read(flowFile);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "utf-8"));
        String content = "", line = null;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
            content += line;
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        println("log.isDebugEnabled():"+ log.isDebugEnabled());
        log.info("BEGIN to TEST XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        log.debug("TEST =================================")
        log.debug("content is {}", content);
        log.debug("1. attribute count {}", flowFile.getAttributes().size());
        session.putAttribute(flowFile, "IN_SIDE_ATTR_1", "ABCD");
        session.putAttribute(flowFile, "IN_SIDE_ATTR_2", "EFGHI");
        log.debug("2. attribute count {}", flowFile.getAttributes().size());
        flowFile.getAttributes().keySet().stream().forEach (key ->{
            String value = flowFile.getAttribute(key);
            log.debug(String.format("In processor: [%s]=[%s]", key, value));
        })
        session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

### TestSampleProcessor.java

```
import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j;
import org.apache.nifi.util.MockFlowFile;
import org.apache.nifi.util.TestRunner;
import org.apache.nifi.util.TestRunners;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

@Slf4j
class TestSampleProcessor {
    private TestRunner testRunner;
    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        testRunner = TestRunners.newTestRunner(SampleProcessor.class);
    }
    @Test
    public void testAddAttribute() {
        String lines = "HELLO, WORLD";
        Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<>();
        attributes.put("ATTR_1_ADD_FROM_OUTSIDE", UUID.randomUUID().toString())
        attributes.put("ATTR_2_ADD_FROM_OUTSIDE", "/Retry")

        testRunner.enqueue(lines, attributes);
        testRunner.run();
        testRunner.assertAllFlowFilesTransferred(SampleProcessor.REL_SUCCESS, 1);
        MockFlowFile flowFile = testRunner.getFlowFilesForRelationship(SampleProcessor.REL_SUCCESS).get(0);
        log.info("Check all attributes");
        flowFile.attributes.keySet().forEach (key-> {
            log.debug(String.format("DEBUG. [%s]=[%s]", key, flowFile.getAttribute(key)))
        })
    }
}
```

### Output:

```
log.isDebugEnabled():true
2023-10-11 09:14:46:895 +0800 INFO SampleProcessor - SampleProcessor[id=39f7be77-f23e-429b-8b59-7a165e3de2ed] BEGIN to TEST XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
2023-10-11 09:14:46:896 +0800 DEBUG SampleProcessor - SampleProcessor[id=39f7be77-f23e-429b-8b59-7a165e3de2ed] TEST =================================
2023-10-11 09:14:46:897 +0800 DEBUG SampleProcessor - SampleProcessor[id=39f7be77-f23e-429b-8b59-7a165e3de2ed] content is HELLO, WORLD
2023-10-11 09:14:46:906 +0800 DEBUG SampleProcessor - SampleProcessor[id=39f7be77-f23e-429b-8b59-7a165e3de2ed] 1. attribute count 5
2023-10-11 09:14:46:906 +0800 DEBUG SampleProcessor - SampleProcessor[id=39f7be77-f23e-429b-8b59-7a165e3de2ed] 2. attribute count 5
2023-10-11 09:14:46:928 +0800 DEBUG SampleProcessor - SampleProcessor[id=39f7be77-f23e-429b-8b59-7a165e3de2ed] In processor: [filename]=[88495457086800.mockFlowFile]
2023-10-11 09:14:46:928 +0800 DEBUG SampleProcessor - SampleProcessor[id=39f7be77-f23e-429b-8b59-7a165e3de2ed] In processor: [path]=[target]
2023-10-11 09:14:46:929 +0800 DEBUG SampleProcessor - SampleProcessor[id=39f7be77-f23e-429b-8b59-7a165e3de2ed] In processor: [uuid]=[7a5fbff1-9d23-43a6-93b6-fd73d8d4974d]
2023-10-11 09:14:46:929 +0800 DEBUG SampleProcessor - SampleProcessor[id=39f7be77-f23e-429b-8b59-7a165e3de2ed] In processor: [ATTR_1_ADD_FROM_OUTSIDE]=[4eac4e85-362f-48f5-806c-33e322104cb1]
2023-10-11 09:14:46:930 +0800 DEBUG SampleProcessor - SampleProcessor[id=39f7be77-f23e-429b-8b59-7a165e3de2ed] In processor: [ATTR_2_ADD_FROM_OUTSIDE]=[/Retry]
2023-10-11 09:14:46:941 +0800 INFO TestSampleProcessor - Check all attributes
2023-10-11 09:14:46:944 +0800 DEBUG TestSampleProcessor - DEBUG. [filename]=[88495457086800.mockFlowFile]
2023-10-11 09:14:46:944 +0800 DEBUG TestSampleProcessor - DEBUG. [path]=[target]
2023-10-11 09:14:46:944 +0800 DEBUG TestSampleProcessor - DEBUG. [uuid]=[7a5fbff1-9d23-43a6-93b6-fd73d8d4974d]
2023-10-11 09:14:46:944 +0800 DEBUG TestSampleProcessor - DEBUG. [ATTR_1_ADD_FROM_OUTSIDE]=[4eac4e85-362f-48f5-806c-33e322104cb1]
2023-10-11 09:14:46:944 +0800 DEBUG TestSampleProcessor - DEBUG. [ATTR_2_ADD_FROM_OUTSIDE]=[/Retry]
2023-10-11 09:14:46:944 +0800 DEBUG TestSampleProcessor - DEBUG. [IN_SIDE_ATTR_1]=[ABCD]
2023-10-11 09:14:46:944 +0800 DEBUG TestSampleProcessor - DEBUG. [IN_SIDE_ATTR_2]=[EFGHI]
```

Answer (score 1):

`session.putAttribute()` returns a FlowFile, basically a reference to the updated FlowFile. But when you use the session to transfer a FlowFile, even if you're referring to the original FlowFile object (which you are in the above code), it is smart enough to know you really want to transfer the latest version of that FlowFile and "updates" it for you. This has the awkward side-effect of not realizing you're using an "old" reference to the original FlowFile instead of the latest version of it.

Try doing this when you call `putAttribute()`:

```
flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, ...
```

That should ensure you are referring to the latest version of the FlowFile and you should see the attributes show up in the `onTrigger()` logging.